# How to upload a text file to Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, samba

I read many examples but none work as intended.
My notions of programming come from more than 30 years ago, and I'm a bit outdated.
I have a text file generated by a script on a server in a directory accessible via samba.
Is it possible to copy that file to Google Drive and pass the content to a spreadsheet using app scripts? Some example? Any suggestion?
I must say that English is not my forte and I use a translator to be able to write.

Thanks

Comment: One way that is pretty simple is to go through dropbox.  They have a standard api.  I upload gps files from my phone to my google account that way.

Comment: About `I have a text file generated by a script on a server in a directory accessible via samba. Is it possible to copy that file to Google Drive and pass the content to a spreadsheet using app scripts?`, in that case, I thought that using a script that can be run on the server might be suitable rather than the use of Google Apps Script. Because Google Apps Script cannot access to `a directory accessible via samba`. For example, when your text file can be retrieved by the HTML request, Google Apps Script might be able to be used. How about this? If my comment was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the answer. In the event that Apps Script cannot access a shared directory via samba, I have the option of saving it locally. My intention is to read the text file and dump it to a spreadsheet and then display it in a browser.

Comment: This is possible with the Drive and Sheets API but I'm not aware of any public examples.